# Node Editor not having any affect on the selected / assigned object or showing in Preview

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I used the Node Editor to make alterations to a material however they are not showing at all. There seems to be a disconnect. I am sure I have done something silly as usual but cant for the life of me figure it out or find an answer. [image]

[image]

Comment: Did you press the **assign** button to  link the faces to the material?

Comment: Make sure you don't have duplicate nodes overlapping a second set bellow them.

Comment: Weird... I don't think that is supposed to happen... Would you be able to give a link to your project at https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so I can view your situation myself?

Comment: @YusaMac205 I have hopefully added the link to the question for you to have a look at. I have been playing around, learning to use Blender  by trial and error this last week. As a consequence I have pressed an awful lot of buttons in order to understand the effects of the nodes so absolutely anything is possible. Most likely very simple.

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos Would this duplicate set not show up in the Nodes Window?

Comment: @cegaton I do believe I assigned the material to the object in question. I also thought I remember at some stage there being a Use Nodes Icon/Button on the actual Material Properties Panel. Does this  disappear  under some circumstances?

Comment: Only if the duplicate is the active one

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. The blend file you uploaded has different (and very chaotic) material nodes, so it no longer reflects what is presented in the question. But even if your get rid of the mess you currently have, and set the materials as in the question, it all works correctly:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeBYt.png.

Comment: You have the strangest material set up I have ever seen... I suggest copying your nodes, deleting the material, and then pasting the nodes into the new material. Also, try rendering your scene. It will give you a better picture of what your node set up really looks like.

Comment: Thanks folks. I noticed a theme running through your comments which is basically my knowledge of materials and nodes sucks. As a beginner user of Blender I followed only a few basic general tutorials last week. I have filled in a few gaps by watching the YouTube tutorial (Blender 2.7 Tutorial # 10 : Intro to Materials & Nodes in Cycles #b3d) and have resolved many of the more fundamental issues like messy, chaotic  and strange material setups. Not sure if I was allowed to mention the tutorial by name but it is perfect for a beginner wrestling with the basics.